# Can't get Data.List functions to work in haskell

Tags: haskell, ghci

I'm building a haskell program, and I want to use the library Data.List. So at the top of my program I've added`import Data.List` and below in one of my functions I've typed `Data.List.isAlpha x` but it gives me a compile error - `Not in scope:`Data.List.isAlpha'`. Any suggestions? I've tried using another function from Data.List and that doesn't work.

Here's the function, but I've tried dumbing it down but its not working either:

`myFunc:: [String] -> String`

`myFunc list =  filter Data.List.isAlpha (Data.List.nub(concat list))`

This function is taking a list of strings, nub'ing then to get rid of duplicates, and then keeping only the characters left that are letters.

Any help would be really useful! Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`isAlpha` is in `Data.Char`, not `Data.List`

```
 import Data.List
 import Data.Char

 myFunc :: [String] -> String
 myFunc ls = filter isAlpha . nub . concat $ ls
```

In the future, I'd suggest not fully qualifying names, just do

```
import Data.List as L
import Data.Char as C

-- Now use `C.isAlpha` and `L.nub`
```

And when searching for functions, I'd suggest [hoogle](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/)

Comment: Thanks! I was using a haskell wiki which I guess is not fragmented.

Comment: @jQwierdy no problem! if ive answered your question, please check the little tickmark beside the answer

Answer (score 5):

The function `isAlpha` is not in `Data.List`. Rather it is in `Data.Char`.